# Get frontName of admin from app/etc/local.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, attributes, xml, admin-controller

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

How can I get the front Name of my admin, to use it in code like this ->

```
$wysiwygConfig = Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(array('add_variables' => false, 'add_widgets' => false, 'files_browser_window_url' => $this->getBaseUrl() . '(there must be frontname)/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/'));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can **read directly from config file** such as `app/etc/local.xml` with:

```
Mage::getConfig()
```

Thus you can use the following:

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName');
```

However, instead of doing this I reckon you should **use the helper that lets you generate admin URLs**:

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminhtml/cms_wysiwyg_images/index/");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::getConfig()->getNode('admin/routers/adminhtml/args/frontName');
```